# Shifting array data structure C#

Tags: arrays, c#-4.0, data-structures, stack, queue

I was curious to know if there is an efficient way to store data into a container that has a maximum amount of values and when that value is reached it start removing the oldest values in order to add new ones. And all this in an ordered fashion (meaning that new data should come after the last new data).

I know I could achieve this using a queue

```
    q.Enqueue(1);   
    q.Enqueue(2);   
    q.Enqueue(3);  // 1 2 3

    q.Dequeue(); // 2 3 
    q.Enqueue(4); // 2 3 4
```

but in order to iterate through the data afterwards requires to transform the queue in an array, which I'm not sure how efficient it is.

Maybe it's better to have an array with a fixed size and have an index that shifts to the start when the array is full and using some modulo magic iterate always backwards to query the data from most recent to less recent. This would be less readable but working and more efficient I guess.

So my question would be, is there a better more readable and efficient way?
And also, what is the efficiency of using ToArray() when using other data structures (e.g. List, Queue, Stack..). When should this be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

At the end I decided to implement my idea. Not sure if this is the best way, but it works well for my needs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DataHolder<T> : IEnumerable
{
    private T[] _data;
    private int _maxSize;
    private int _currIdx;
    private int _currSize;

    public DataHolder(int size)
    {
        _maxSize = size;
        _data = new T[_maxSize];
        _currIdx = -1;
        _currSize = 0;
    }

    public void Add(T data)
    {
        if (_currSize < _maxSize) _currSize++;

        _currIdx = NioUtils.PositiveMod((_currIdx + 1),  _maxSize);
        _data[_currIdx] = data;
    }

    ///<summary>
    /// Gets the element at index. The 0 element is the last one added.
    ///</summary>
    public T GetElementAt(int index)
    {
        if (index >= _currSize)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Index out of bounds exception.", "index");
        }

        int shiftIndex = NioUtils.PositiveMod((_currIdx - index), _maxSize);
        return _data[shiftIndex];
    }

    /// Implement interface IEnumerable in order to iterate throught this object.
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        int count = 0;
        int index = _currIdx;
        while (count < _currSize)
        {
            count++;
            yield return _data[index];
            index = NioUtils.PositiveMod((index - 1), _maxSize);
        }
    }

}
```

Where PositiveMod is:

```
public static int PositiveMod(int value, int n)
{
    int v = value % n;
    return v >= 0 ? v : n + v;
}
```